# How to assign value to a null pointer given as an argument to a function?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

When I try to assign value to a NULL pointer I get segmentation fault. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct test {
    int val;
};

void insert(test* t, int value) {
    test* x = (test*)malloc(sizeof(test*));
    x->val = value;
    t = x;
}

int main() {
    test* a = NULL;
    insert(a, 5);
    cout << (a->val) << endl;
}
```

I was expecting it would print 5, but it doesnt. I need to assign a value to a given pointer, inside a function. How can I do that?

Comment: Change `void insert(test* t, int value)` to `void insert(test*& t, int value)`

Comment: And then you need to fix the wrong size you pass to `malloc`. Or you use actual C++ with `new test` (assuming there's any real reason for using dynamic memory allocations in the first place)

Comment: This is the third question I've seen *today* trying to use `malloc` in C++, where is this coming from?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug:

```
test* x = (test*)malloc(sizeof(test*));
```

Should be:

```
test* x = (test*)malloc(sizeof(test));
```

Now bringing it all home, let's return the newly allocated pointer:

```
test* insert(int value) {
    test* x = (test*)malloc(sizeof(test));
    x->val = value;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    test* a = insert(5);
    cout << (a->val) << endl;

    // and let's free "a" while we can
    free(a);
}
```

Comment: This is only half the problem

Comment: OP passes the pointer by value

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are no different from anything else:  when used as a function argument they are passed by value.

So `insert(a,5)` in `main()` passes a copy of `a` to the function, and the change of the argument in the function is then not visible to the caller.

So, when control returns to `main()`, the value `a` is not changed.  It is still the null pointer, and evaluating `a->val` gives undefined behaviour.

To fix either pass by reference.

```
void insert(test *&t, int value)     // note the & here
{
    test* x = (test*)malloc(sizeof(*x));
    x->val = value;
    t = x;
}

int main()
{
    test* a = NULL;
    insert(a, 5);
    cout << (a->val) << endl;
}
```

Note, also, that I have corrected the argument passed to `malloc()` since you got it wrong.   You passed `sizeof(test *)` and really needed to pass it as `sizeof(test)`.   I have used the technique of passing `sizeof(*x)` since that will work even if (say) you change the type of the pointer to something else.

or pass a pointer to a pointer (`test **`)

```
void insert(test **t, int value)     // note the additional * here
{
    test* x = (test*)malloc(sizeof(*x));
    x->val = value;
    *t = x;                          // note the additional * here
}

int main()
{
    test* a = NULL;
    insert(&a, 5);                   // also note the & here
    cout << (a->val) << endl;
}
```

Of the two options above, passing by reference (not pointer) is usually considered preferable in C++.  Passing a pointer to a pointer is common in C, and (mostly) discouraged in C++.

More generally, it is usually preferable to use operator `new` and avoid `malloc()` entirely in C++.   Among other things, it eliminates the possibility (which you demonstrated) of getting an operand of `sizeof` wrong.     So, instead of doing

```
test* x = (test*)malloc(sizeof(*x));
```

do

```
test* x = new test;
```